# Manipulating change of variables formula for multiple integrals with roots

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multiple-integral

The change of variables for multiple integral can be formulated like:

$\int_D(f \circ g) (x) |det~J_g(x)|dx = \int_{D'}fdx'$

for a continous $f: D'\rightarrow X$ and two-times continous, injective $g: D \rightarrow D'$.

I wonder what happens with the function:
$$l(n) = \int_D(f \circ g) (x) \sqrt[\textbf{n}]{|det~J_g(d)|}dx$$
assuming $\int_{D'}fdx$ is finite (which is $l(1)$). Or maybe: are there any (interesting) constraints that one could put upon $f$ or $g$ so that $l(n)$ is (for example) continous?

Comment: $f(n)$ is a bad notation, because you have function $f$ already

Comment: sry, just noticed it. I also noticed another error, will correct

Comment: I just want to add that I am a bit confused by the change of variables for multiple integrals. Which constraints which definition of an integral imposes and what notion is generally understood as to be the "classical" change of variables for multiple integrals. So my formulation may be wrong, but at least imprecise. I hope my question still makes sense!

Comment: Also, i don't think the title makes sense, but I can't come up with one that does